# how to user regex replace special characters in java

Tags: java, regex

characters:

```
 + – && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ ” ~ * ? : \
```

now i want to replace the character with \ 
example:

```
String s ="content:you&&me";
```

after replace:

```
s--> content\:you\&&me
```

someone help me thank you

Comment: Take a look at the java classes Pattern and Matcher.  Once you've done that you will be able to answer the question "What have you tried?".  Then we can help you further.

Comment: you want to replace it with `/`, but in the expected result, you've shown **\\**?

Comment: sorry is \ , I have mistakes

Comment: I have tried,but the + and some other characters is special in regex.I have error Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+ – && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ ” ~ * ? : \

Comment: and I have tried to add \\ or [] in + but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly then this problem seems to be tricky. You can try this code to solve your task:

```
// your special characters
String regex = "+ – && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ ” ~ * ? : \\";
// building a valid regex out of above
regex = '(' + regex.replaceAll("([^\\s]{1,2})(?=(?:\\s+|$))",
                               "\\\\Q$1\\\\E").replace(' ', '|') + ')';

// your string to be replaced
String str = "content:you&&me";
// actual replacement
str = str.replaceAll(regex, "\\\\$1");

// printing the result
System.out.printf("********* replaced: [%s]%n", str);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/onmcMy

Comment: yeah,I'm so sorry that my bad English might be make you confused.

Comment: I test your answer,it is right.anyway,thank you very much

Comment: If you think this answer helped you then mark it as accepted.